# Xubuntu installation on HP Stream 14 - can't see the eMMC drive

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu, hp

I have just bought an HP Stream 14 to use as a netbook. I want to get rid of Windows and install Xubuntu (which I did on an HP Stream 11 without difficulty).

When I load Xubuntu from a usb stick, it cannot see the 64GB eMMC drive, so I can't install to it.

Is there a way round this available now, or do I have to wait for the linux kernel to catch up with this device, or am I doomed to have to use Windows?

Comment: [This answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1303307/1091774) might help you with the invisible eMMC issue 

Comment: It was the 20.04.2 LTS release downloaded yesterday - I also tried Manjaro XFCE with the same result

Comment: Matigo - the bios tells me that the TPM Device is 'Available' and the TPM State is 'Enable', there is no Legacy Option that I've been able to find

Comment: @Matigo I am tagging you because Andy did not write "@", so you probably did not receive a notification (or did you?)

Comment: Many new systems are using UEFI class 3 which has no legacy option. Do you have drive set to AHCI? Is fast boot off, UEFI Secure Boot off, and UEFI updated to latest? Does it have Optane?

Comment: There is no option to set/unset AHCI or fast boot, I've tried with secure boot on or off. I've no idea if it has optane.